# При 12 ядрах, забивается только одно

Tags: java

[image: 1]

Когда нагрузка под 100%, сервер жестко начинает лагать. 
Может быть, можно как-нибудь распределить нагрузку?

Сервер написан на Java, с использованием netty (12 * 2 = всего 24 потока).

OS: CentOS 7.0 x86-64

Comment: Возможность распределения нагрузки между ядрами - это вопрос к коду. Профилируйте, определяйте какая именно часть кода грузит процессор, а потом уже можно выяснять, можно ли этот код переписать так, чтобы он распределял нагрузку между разными ядрами и не приведёт ли это к ещё большему падению производительности.